# What is a logical approach to tracking IPv6 connections for abuse?

Tags: security, ipv6, hacking, reporting

I have a web server that issues AAAA records and I want to understand how I should monitor that interface for abuse.

Specifically, how should I dice up that address to determine hacking or brute force of my app?

Is the only aspect of IPv6 I can rely on being administratively controlled is the GlobalID?

Is there any database that informs me of well known subnets, etc?